# Test-first-ruby 13_xml_document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am working on test-first-ruby-master (you can find it at https://github.com/appacademy/test-first-ruby).

The 13_xml_document_spec.rb is the Rspec test that my code must pass. This test has several tasks, but it is the last one (called "indents") that my code doesn't accomplish.

Here is the Rspec test:

```
require "13_xml_document"


describe XmlDocument do
  before do
    @xml = XmlDocument.new
  end

  it "renders an empty tag" do
    expect(@xml.hello).to eq("<hello/>")
  end

  it "renders a tag with attributes" do
    expect(@xml.hello(:name => "dolly")).to eq('<hello name="dolly"/>')
  end

  it "renders a randomly named tag" do
    tag_name = (1..8).map{|i| ("a".."z").to_a[rand(26)]}.join
    expect(@xml.send(tag_name)).to eq("<#{tag_name}/>")
  end

  it "renders block with text inside" do
    expect(@xml.hello { "dolly" }).to eq("<hello>dolly</hello>")
  end

  it "nests one level" do
    expect(@xml.hello { @xml.goodbye }).to eq("<hello><goodbye/></hello>")
  end

  it "nests several levels" do
    xml = XmlDocument.new

    xml_string = xml.hello do
      xml.goodbye do
        xml.come_back do
          xml.ok_fine(:be => "that_way")
        end
      end
    end

    expect(xml_string).to eq('<hello><goodbye><come_back><ok_fine 
be="that_way"/></come_back></goodbye></hello>')
  end

  it "indents" do
    @xml = XmlDocument.new(true)

    xml_string = @xml.hello do
      @xml.goodbye do
        @xml.come_back do
          @xml.ok_fine(:be => "that_way")
        end
      end
    end

    expect(xml_string).to eq(
      "<hello>\n" +
      "  <goodbye>\n" +
      "    <come_back>\n" +
      "      <ok_fine be=\"that_way\"/>\n" +
      "    </come_back>\n" +
      "  </goodbye>\n" +
      "</hello>\n"
    )
  end

end
```

And here is my code:

```
class XmlDocument

def initialize(indentation = false)
    @indentation = indentation
    @counter = 0
end

def method_missing(method, *args, &block) 

    hash = {}

    if block
        if @indentation == false
            "<#{method}>#{yield}</#{method}>"
        elsif @indentation == true

            string = ""

            string << indent1 
            string << "<#{method}>\n"
                (###)
            add_indent

            string << indent1
            string <<  yield + "\n" 

            sub_indent 

            string << indent2
            string << "</#{method}\>"

            string   
        end

    elsif args[0].is_a?(Hash)

        args[0].map { |key,value| "<#{method.to_s} #{key.to_s}=\"#{value.to_s}\"/>" }.join(" ")

    elsif hash.empty?

       "<#{method.to_s}/>"
    end           
end


def indent1
    " " * @counter
end


def indent2
    "  " * @counter
end


def add_indent     
    @counter += 1
end


def sub_indent
    @counter -= 1   
end
end
```

This is the output I get for the "indents" part:

```
    <hello>
      <goodbye>
        <come_back>
   +   <ok_fine be="that_way"/>
        </come_back>
      </goodbye>
    </hello>
```

Contrary to the right answer, the 4th line ('ok_fine be="that_way"/') seems be two indents closer to the left than it is supposed to be. As opposed to the rest of the lines, the 4th line is not a block, but an argument of the called method 'come_back'.
I cannot see where my mistake is. Even writing an exception in the code (where the (###) is in my code) doesn't seem to have any effect on the 4th line.

Here is the exception (###):

```
if args[0].is_a?(Hash)
   add_indent
   string << indent
   arg[0].map{|key, value| string << "<#{method.to_s} #{key.to_s}=\"#{value.to_s}\"/>"}
end
```

NOTE: I assume that if I manage to give the 4th line the right numbers of indents, that also will increase the number of indents of the lines after it, so the method 'indent2' will need to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. As I said in my question, in the Rspec test they have the following input:

```
xml_string = xml.hello do
  xml.goodbye do
    xml.come_back do
      xml.ok_fine(:be => "that_way")
    end
  end
end
```

where the 4th line (`xml.ok_fine(:be => "that_way")`) doesn't have a block nested, but an argument. In my code I established a condition (if block) for when there is a block present and inside this first condition, a second condition (`if @indentation == true`) for when @indentation is true:

```
 if block
    if @indentation == false
        "<#{method}>#{yield}</#{method}>"
    elsif @indentation == true
            ...
```

It is inside this second condition that I create the variable 'string' where I shovel in the different parts:

```
elsif @indentation == true

        string = ""

        string << indent1 
        string << "<#{method}>\n"
            (###)
        add_indent

        string << indent1
        string <<  yield + "\n" 

        sub_indent 

        string << indent2
        string << "</#{method}\>"

        string   
    end
```

But because the 4th line doesn't carry a block, the first condition (if block) doesn't return true for it and therefore this 4th line is skipped.

I've re-written my code so now it passes the Rspec test:

```
class XmlDocument

def initialize(indentation = false)
    @indentation = indentation
    @counter = 0
end

def method_missing(method, args = nil, &block) 
    string = ""
    arguments = args

    if @indentation == false
        if (arguments == nil) && (block == nil)
            "<#{method.to_s}/>"

        elsif arguments.is_a?(Hash)
            arguments.map { |key,value| "<#{method.to_s} #{key.to_s}=\"#{value.to_s}\"/>" }.join(" ")

        elsif block 
            "<#{method}>#{yield}</#{method}>"
        end

    elsif @indentation == true 

        if (block) || (arguments.is_a?(Hash))

            string << indent1
            string << "<#{method}>\n" unless !block
            add_indent 
            string << indent1 unless !block

            if block
                string <<  yield + "\n" 
            elsif arguments.is_a?(Hash)
                arguments.map { |key,value| string << "<#{method.to_s} #{key.to_s}=\"#{value.to_s}\"/>" }
            end
            sub_indent 
            string << indent2 unless !block
            string << "</#{method}\>" unless !block

            if indent2 == ""
                string << "\n"
            end
        end
        string
    end
end

def indent1
    " " * @counter
end

def indent2
    "  " * @counter
end

def add_indent
    @counter += 1
end

def sub_indent
    @counter -= 1
end
```

end

In contrast to the code I wrote in my question, in this one, the two main conditions are `@indentation == false` and `@indentation == true` and inside these two conditions I establish different exceptions for the different cases (block or no block, argument or no argument...). Specifically for `elsif @indentation == true` I created a condition that accepts the 4th line: `if (block) || (arguments.is_a?(Hash))`, or in other words, it accepts methods that have a block or an argument (especifically a a hash).

Now, I shovel in the different parts in 'string', and when I reach a block to yield there is a bifurcation:

```
    if block
       string <<  yield + "\n" 
    elsif arguments.is_a?(Hash)
       arguments.map { |key,value| string << "<#{method.to_s} #{key.to_s}=\"#{value.to_s}\"/>" }
```

if there is a block I "yield" it, and if there is and argument that is a hash I shovel it into 'string'.

Also, there is this exception `unless !block` either when I indent or I shovel a method because otherwise it can introduce unwanted indents and '\n' if there is a method that doesn't have a block (as line 4th).

Finally, I had to add at the end

```
 if indent2 == ""
    string << "\n"
 end
```

because the solution requires a '\n' at the end.

I hope this answer can help other

NOTE: I wrote a 'NOTE' in my question where I assumed I would have to modify 'indent2'. That, obviously I didn't have to do because the output I was getting did not considered the 4th line (because it doesn't have a block), so the bigger indentation ("  ") of 'indent2' is all right.